# splitting an array with one item into an array with many items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, split

I have an array that returns the following item:

```html
["\nOnprogress\nDone"]
```

I want to turn it into an array that splits this item into two items like this:

```html
["Onprogress" , "Done"]
```

I also want to remove the unnecessary '\n' characters without removing the 'n' characters from the words themselves. As demonstrated above ^. Any ideas how to do that?

This is my code:

```html
    addCardtoApp = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const card = {
            taskName: this.taskName.current.value, 
            taskDescription: this.taskDescription.current.value,
            taskPeriod: this.taskPeriod.current.value,
        };
        const cardStatus = this.taskStatus.current.value;
        let otherStatus = {
            otherStatus: this.taskStatus.current.innerText,
        };
        const replacedStatus = otherStatus.otherStatus.replace(`${cardStatus}`, '');
        const convertedStatus = replacedStatus.split(" ");
        const refinedStatus = JSON.stringify(convertedStatus).replace(/↵/, '');
        console.log(refinedStatus);
        this.props.addCard(card, cardStatus, replacedStatus);
        event.currentTarget.reset();
    };
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and split the string. Then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out empty items:

```js
const arr = ["\nOnprogress\nDone"]

const result = arr
  .flatMap(str => str.split('\n'))
  .filter(Boolean) // or .filter(s => s.length > 0) for the sake of readability

console.log(result)
```

And if flatMap is not supported, you can use `Array.map()`, spread, and `Array.concat()`:

```js
const arr = ["\nOnprogress\nDone"]

const result = [].concat(...arr.map(str => str.split('\n')))
  .filter(Boolean) // or .filter(s => s.length > 0) for the sake of readability

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I know how to use `flatMap()` :).

Comment: .flatMap is not a function ... @ori Drori

Comment: You're using IE/Edge. I've added another solution that will work for those browsers.

Comment: TypeError: refinedStatus.map is not a function .... Also why are you concatenating an empty array?  @OriDrori

Comment: I think I know where the problem is, console thinks its a string while its an array and if I convert into an array it creates an array inside and array ... Don't know how to solve it ...

Comment: Create a small test case, and open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` and `splice`

```js
var a=["\nOnprogress\nDone"]
var arr=a.map(e=>e.split("\n")[0]==""?e.split("\n").splice(1):e.split("\n"))
console.log(arr.flat(1))
```

Comment: I dont tihnk you need to define the 2nd argument for splice in this case.

Comment: While this will log the values, it doesn't return them anywhere for further use.

Comment: Would be nicer if it worked on something like `["Onprogress\nDone"]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could take `match` instead of `split` and search for non linefeed characters.

```js
console.log("\nOnprogress\nDone".match(/[^\n]+/g));
```